problem with showing students marklist in laravel
"I first fetch the list of students through Laravel, and for each student, I want to display their report card. The report card displays correctly in the preview section, but when I click on the print button, the report card is repeated four times. The bottom part of the report card is also not displayed correctly. For this, I used Laravel and Livewire. Here's the code I've written."
the view Code goes here
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="showStudent">
        <div class="selectbox" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 15px; padding: 20px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);">
        <div class="row align-items-center">

            <div class="col-md-4 mx-4">
              <label class="block font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-zinc-100 mb-2">سال تحصیلی</label>
              <select wire:model="selectedYear" class="dark:bg-zinc-800 dark:border-zinc-700 w-full rounded border-gray-100 py-2.5 text-sm text-gray-500 focus:border focus:border-violet-500 focus:ring-0 dark:bg-zinc-700/50 dark:text-zinc-100" required>
                <option value="">انتخاب سال تحصیلی</option>
                @foreach($years as $year)
                  <option value="{{ $year->id }}">{{ $year->title }}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          
            <div class="col-md-4 mx-4">
              <label class="block font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-zinc-100 mb-2">پایه تحصیلی</label>
              <select wire:model="selectedGrade" class="dark:bg-zinc-800 dark:border-zinc-700 w-full rounded border-gray-100 py-2.5 text-sm text-gray-500 focus:border focus:border-violet-500 focus:ring-0 dark:bg-zinc-700/50 dark:text-zinc-100" required>
                <option value="">انتخاب پایه</option>
                @foreach($grades as $grade)
                  <option value="{{ $grade->id }}">{{ $grade->title }}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          
            <div class="col-md-4 align-self-end mt-8">
              <button wire:click="showStudent" class="btn text-white bg-violet-500 border-violet-500 hover:bg-violet-600">نمایش کارنامه</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          
    
        
    
       
    
        
    </form>
    @if(!empty($students) && count($students) > 0)
    <table class="w-full text-sm text-right text-gray-500">
      <thead class="text-xs text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-100 uppercase bg-gray-50/50 dark:bg-zinc-700/50">
          <tr>
              <th scope="col" class="p-3">
                  <div class="flex items-center">
                      <input id="checkbox-all" type="checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 focus:ring-0 focus:outline-0 border-gray-100 focus:ring-offset-0 rounded dark:bg-zinc-700 dark:border-zinc-500 dark:checked:bg-violet-500">
                      <label for="checkbox-all" class="sr-only">چک باکس</label>
                  </div>
              </th>
              <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                  نام 
              </th>
              <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                  نام خانوادگی
              </th>
              <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                  عملیات 
              </th>
              
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($students as $index => $student)
          <tr class="bg-white border-b border-gray-100  hover:bg-gray-50/50 dark:bg-zinc-700 dark:hover:bg-zinc-700/50 dark:border-zinc-600">
              <td class="w-4 p-2">
                  <div class="flex items-center">                                                        
                      <input id="checkbox-all" type="checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 focus:ring-0 focus:outline-0 border-gray-100 focus:ring-offset-0 rounded dark:bg-zinc-700 dark:border-zinc-500 dark:checked:bg-violet-500">
                      <label for="checkbox-all" class="sr-only">چک باکس</label>
                  </div>
              </td>
              <th scope="row" class="px-6 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                {{ $student->student->firstName ?? 'N/A' }}
              </th>
              <td class="px-6 py-2">
                {{ $student->student->lastName ?? 'N/A' }}
              </td>
             
             
              <td class="px-6 py-4">
                  <a wire:click="viewMarks({{$student->id}})" href="javascript:void(0)"  class="font-medium text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline">مشاهده کارنامه</a>
              </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
          
      </tbody>
  </table>
  @endif
  
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="showStudent">
        <div class="selectbox" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 15px; padding: 20px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);">
        <div class="row align-items-center">

            <div class="col-md-4 mx-4">
              <label class="block font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-zinc-100 mb-2">سال تحصیلی</label>
              <select wire:model="selectedYear" class="dark:bg-zinc-800 dark:border-zinc-700 w-full rounded border-gray-100 py-2.5 text-sm text-gray-500 focus:border focus:border-violet-500 focus:ring-0 dark:bg-zinc-700/50 dark:text-zinc-100" required>
                <option value="">انتخاب سال تحصیلی</option>
                @foreach($years as $year)
                  <option value="{{ $year->id }}">{{ $year->title }}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          
            <div class="col-md-4 mx-4">
              <label class="block font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-zinc-100 mb-2">پایه تحصیلی</label>
              <select wire:model="selectedGrade" class="dark:bg-zinc-800 dark:border-zinc-700 w-full rounded border-gray-100 py-2.5 text-sm text-gray-500 focus:border focus:border-violet-500 focus:ring-0 dark:bg-zinc-700/50 dark:text-zinc-100" required>
                <option value="">انتخاب پایه</option>
                @foreach($grades as $grade)
                  <option value="{{ $grade->id }}">{{ $grade->title }}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          
            <div class="col-md-4 align-self-end mt-8">
              <button wire:click="showStudent" class="btn text-white bg-violet-500 border-violet-500 hover:bg-violet-600">نمایش کارنامه</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          
    
        
    
       
    
        
    </form>
    @if(!empty($students) && count($students) > 0)
    <table class="w-full text-sm text-right text-gray-500">
      <thead class="text-xs text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-100 uppercase bg-gray-50/50 dark:bg-zinc-700/50">
          <tr>
              <th scope="col" class="p-3">
                  <div class="flex items-center">
                      <input id="checkbox-all" type="checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 focus:ring-0 focus:outline-0 border-gray-100 focus:ring-offset-0 rounded dark:bg-zinc-700 dark:border-zinc-500 dark:checked:bg-violet-500">
                      <label for="checkbox-all" class="sr-only">چک باکس</label>
                  </div>
              </th>
              <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                  نام 
              </th>
              <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                  نام خانوادگی
              </th>
              <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                  عملیات 
              </th>
              
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($students as $index => $student)
          <tr class="bg-white border-b border-gray-100  hover:bg-gray-50/50 dark:bg-zinc-700 dark:hover:bg-zinc-700/50 dark:border-zinc-600">
              <td class="w-4 p-2">
                  <div class="flex items-center">                                                        
                      <input id="checkbox-all" type="checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 focus:ring-0 focus:outline-0 border-gray-100 focus:ring-offset-0 rounded dark:bg-zinc-700 dark:border-zinc-500 dark:checked:bg-violet-500">
                      <label for="checkbox-all" class="sr-only">چک باکس</label>
                  </div>
              </td>
              <th scope="row" class="px-6 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                {{ $student->student->firstName ?? 'N/A' }}
              </th>
              <td class="px-6 py-2">
                {{ $student->student->lastName ?? 'N/A' }}
              </td>
             
             
              <td class="px-6 py-4">
                  <a wire:click="viewMarks({{$student->id}})" href="javascript:void(0)"  class="font-medium text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline">مشاهده کارنامه</a>
              </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
          
      </tbody>
  </table>
  @endif
  
 
  @if($showReportCard && $selectedStudent)
    <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity z-50 print:bg-white print:bg-opacity-100">
        <div class="fixed inset-0 z-50 overflow-y-auto print:relative print:top-0">
            <div class="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0 print:block print:p-0">
                <div class="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white text-right shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-4xl print:shadow-none print:w-full print:max-w-none print:m-0 print:rounded-none">
                    <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                        <!-- Header with Print and Close Buttons -->
                        <div class="flex justify-between items-center mb-4 print:hidden">
                            <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
                                کارنامه دانش آموز
                            </h3>
                            <div class="flex gap-2">
                                <button 
                                    onclick="window.print()"
                                    class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-violet-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-violet-600"
                                >
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5 ml-2" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M17 17h2a2 2 0 002-2v-4a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v4a2 2 0 002 2h2m2 4h6a2 2 0 002-2v-4a2 2 0 00-2-2H9a2 2 0 00-2 2v4a2 2 0 002 2zm8-12V5a2 2 0 00-2-2H9a2 2 0 00-2 2v4h10z" />
                                    </svg>
                                    چاپ کارنامه
                                </button>
                                <button 
                                    wire:click="closeReportCard"
                                    class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 rounded hover:bg-gray-300"
                                >
                                    بستن
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Printable Content -->
                        <div class="print:p-4">
                            <!-- Report Card Header -->
                            <div class="text-center border-b-2 border-gray-200 pb-4 mb-6">
                                <h2 class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">کارنامه تحصیلی</h2>
                                <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 text-right">
                                    <div>
                                        <span class="font-semibold ml-2">نام و نام خانوادگی:</span>
                                        {{ $selectedStudent->student->firstName }} {{ $selectedStudent->student->lastName }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span class="font-semibold ml-2">سال تحصیلی:</span>
                                        {{ $getyear->title }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Grades Table -->
                            <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300 border border-gray-300">
                                <thead class="bg-gray-50">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="border border-gray-300 py-3.5 px-4 text-right text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">ردیف</th>
                                        <th class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3.5 text-right text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">نام درس</th>
                                        @foreach($reportCardData['examTypes'] as $examType)
                                            <th class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3.5 text-right text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">
                                                {{ $examType->title }}
                                            </th>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200 bg-white">
                                    @foreach($reportCardData['books'] as $index => $bookData)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="border border-gray-300 py-4 px-4 text-sm text-center text-gray-900">
                                                {{ $index + 1 }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-4 text-sm text-gray-900">
                                                {{ $bookData['book']->fullTitle }}
                                            </td>
                                            @foreach($reportCardData['examTypes'] as $examType)
                                                <td class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-4 text-sm text-center text-gray-900">
                                                    {{ $bookData['marks'][$examType->id] ?? '-' }}
                                                </td>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                    <tr class="bg-gray-50 font-bold">
                                        <td class="border border-gray-300 py-4 px-4 text-sm text-center text-gray-900">-</td>
                                        <td class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-4 text-sm text-gray-900">معدل</td>
                                        @foreach($reportCardData['examTypes'] as $examType)
                                            <td class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-4 text-sm text-center text-gray-900">
                                                {{ $averages[$examType->id] ?? '-' }}
                                            </td>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <!-- Signatures Section -->
                            <div class="mt-8 text-center border-t-2 border-gray-200 pt-4">
                                <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 mt-4">
                                    <div>
                                        <p class="font-semibold mb-2">مدیر مدرسه</p>
                                        <div class="h-16 border-b border-gray-300 mt-8"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p class="font-semibold mb-2">معاون آموزشی</p>
                                        <div class="h-16 border-b border-gray-300 mt-8"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p class="font-semibold mb-2">مهر آموزشگاه</p>
                                        <div class="h-16 border-b border-gray-300 mt-8"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>
        @media print {
            @page {
                size: A4;
                margin: 1.5cm;
            }

            body * {
                visibility: hidden;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .fixed {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .print\:hidden {
                display: none !important;
            }

            .print\:block {
                display: block !important;
            }

            .print\:p-4 {
                padding: 1rem !important;
            }

            .fixed *,
            #printable-section,
            #printable-section * {
                visibility: visible;
            }

            .bg-gray-500 {
                background: none !important;
            }

            table {
                width: 100% !important;
                border-collapse: collapse !important;
            }

            th, td {
                border: 1px solid #000 !important;
                padding: 8px !important;
            }

            .transform {
                transform: none !important;
            }

            .transition-opacity {
                transition: none !important;
            }

            .shadow-xl {
                box-shadow: none !important;
            }

            .rounded-lg {
                border-radius: 0 !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
@endif


</div>


body * {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* Ensure no extra spacing for the printable content */
.fixed {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.transform, .transition-opacity, .shadow-xl, .rounded-lg {
    display: none !important; /* Disable unnecessary animations */
}

This CSS will hide everything except the printable content. Ensure the content you want to print is within a container that has an ID like #printable-section and apply .print\:block only to that specific container.
If the bottom part of the report card is not displaying correctly, it might be due to content overflow or not enough space on the printed page. Check the @page CSS rule for proper margins. You may need to increase the margin or adjust the layout to fit the entire report card.
